# If a group has only one commutator, why does that mean it is abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I understand that if $aba^{-1}b^{-1} = e$ then $ab$ is commutative, but I don't see how having multiple commutators will prevent the group from being abelian

Comment: If $aba^{-1}b^{-1} = c \ne e$, then $ab=cba$, so $ab \ne ba$.

Comment: such a simple connection that I couldn't make, thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to see the contrapositive: If a group *is* abelian, then $e$ is its only commutator:

$$aba^{-1}b^{-1} = aa^{-1}bb^{-1} = ee = e $$

Therefore, if the group has more than one commutator, at least one of them will be different from $e$, and so the group cannot be abelian.